# Trouble Making array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble in making array in javascript. First I made like this

```
for(var i=1; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
    {  
        product[i-1] = [{
            'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
            'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
            'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
            'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
            'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
            'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
            'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
            'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
            'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
            'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
            'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
            'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
        }];
    }
```

After passing it as argument in ajax post I can see that it passing it as

```
product[0][0][minimum]  
product[0][0][model]    326
product[0][0][name] apple mac power
product[0][0][price]    100.0000
product[0][0][product_id]   50
product[0][0][quantity] 5
product[0][0][reward]   0
product[0][0][shipping] 1
product[0][0][subtract] 1
product[0][0][tax_class_i...    0
product[0][0][total]    500
product[0][0][weight]   0.00000000
product[1][0][minimum]  
product[1][0][model]    326
product[1][0][name] apple mac power
product[1][0][price]    100.0000
product[1][0][product_id]   50
product[1][0][quantity] 7
product[1][0][reward]   0
product[1][0][shipping] 1
product[1][0][subtract] 1
product[1][0][tax_class_i...    0
product[1][0][total]    700
```

but I want something like this

```
product[0][name] = "apple mac power"
```

so I changed my code to this

```
for(var i=1; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
{  
    product = [{
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    }];
}
```

So after doing this it is showing only array of 1 row no matter of how many rowCount I have like this

```
product[0][minimum]  
product[0][model]    326
product[0][name] apple mac power
product[0][price]    100.0000
product[0][product_id]   50
product[0][quantity] 7
product[0][reward]   0
product[0][shipping] 1
product[0][subtract] 1
product[0][tax_class_i...    0
product[0][total]    700
```

Can anyone help me.?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version, you are assigning an array to array so, It is displaying as 2d array. and in you second version you are always assigning your product variable to new value, so it is containing only one product information. So you can update your first version by removing [ and ] like

```
for(var i=1; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
{
    product[i-1] = {
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    };
}
```

or you can modify your second version as

```
for(var i=1; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
{  
    product.push({
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    });
}
```

Hope It will help.

Comment: thanks..Actually all answers were correct but accept yours because you gave two ways to do it..so it may help others to choose from any two ways.. @AresAvatar has written a nice explanation.. thanks you all..

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an array of arrays.  Take out the second array, like this:

```
for(var i=1; i <= rowCount-1; i++)
{  
    product[i-1] = {        // Removed array open
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    };       // Removed array close
}
```

In JavaScript, [ ] creates an array, so [ {object} ] creates a single cell array.

Also keep in mind that product[0]["name"] is the same as product[0].name -- in JavaScript, a property can also be used in index syntax.  product is your array, each cell in the array is an object, which has properties including name.

Answer (score 1):

```
product[0]['name'] = "apple mac power"
```

or

```
product[0].name = "apple mac power"
```

instead of

```
product[0][name] = "apple mac power"
```

your first way is good, but you add an array with an hash inside
only remove the [] around

```
product[i-1] = {
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    };
```

instead of

```
product[i-1] = [{
        'product_id' : $('#product_id' + i).val(),
        'name' : $('#item' + i).val(),
        'model' : $('#model' + i).val(),
        'reward' : $('#reward' +i).val(),
        'subtract' : $('#subtract' + i).val(),
        'minimum' : $('#minimum' + i).val(),
        'shipping' : $('#shipping' + i).val(),
        'tax_class_id' : $('#tax_class_id' + i).val(),
        'weight' : $('#weight' + i).val(),
        'quantity' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').val(),
        'price' : $('table.order-table tbody tr[id=\''+ i +'\']').find('td.price').html(),
        'total' : $('table.order-table tbody tr td.quantity input[name=\'quantity'+ i +'\']').parent().parent().find('td.total').html()
    }];
```